# No response when clicking on "Manage Nuget Packages for Solution" in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Need to use MathNet.Numerics and so needed to install the relevant Nuget package. Did not install as I was on .NET Framework 4.5 and needed 4.6.1 or higher. Updated my project to 4.7.2. Now when I try to install I get no reaction when I click on "Manage Nuget Packages for Solution" in Visual Studio.

I tried a repair install which did not work and then deleted the ComponentModelCache folder based on another StackOverflow thread. No luck and the .NET Framework version is now 4.8 after repair install and update.

(I"m using Visual Studio Community 2019 v 16.11.17)

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of these should resolve your issue :]

1. open the visual studio installer and update visual studio if any updates are available
2. disconnect and reconnect your wifi
3. open the package manager console and type in
   `Install-Package MathNet.Numerics -Version 5.0.0`

do any of these work?

Comment: I've just done the update prior to posting my question. I tried 3. and it works! Thanks so much.

Comment: No worries! if you could mark this as a solution, that'd be great! :]

Comment: @Veritas if you ever need to install another package you can find these commands at nuget.org :]